# how to attributes for customer UIButon

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a button that I am trying to add a border to like this:
.h

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
```

.m

```
@implementation MyButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {


    }

    self.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];

    return self;
}
```

The border is not set, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the Quartz framework linked?

Answer (score 1):

UIButton is not meant to be subclassed, I recommend using a category if all you are trying to do is style buttons. Here is an example category to accomplish what you want... note that this has not been run through a compiler, but you get the idea:

UIButton+Styles.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (Styles)

-(void)styleWithBorderColor:(UIColor *)color;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "UIButton+Styles.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIButton (CURStyles)
-(void)styleWithBorderColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;        
}
@end
```

Now when you want to style a button simply import the category and call it like so:

```
[myButton styleWithBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

EDIT:
Please see comments... these should be prefixed to avoid confusion with framework methods

Comment: You should really prefix category methods

Comment: Paul is correct. Please see these guidelines https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html The method above should be prefixed with three letters "xyz_styleWithBorderColor"

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Also if you are creating your button via Nib or Storyboard file initWithFrame method will not be called. In such a case do not forget to place your additional code in awakeFromNib method

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with subclassing UIButton at all.. I suggest maybe you need to set

```
self.backgroundColor = nil; // or [UIColor clearColor]
self.layer.backgroundColor = desiredBackgroundColor.CGColor;
```

The backgroundcolor in UIView covers the border on the layer, move the background color to the layer instead to put it behind (and clip it to) the border